# Merge two dataframes by time and variable ID with NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, data.table, sqldf

Im currently working with some currencies in R and want to merge or override two datasets to create one.

For all the currencies, I have data from 1980 to 2017 in `DF1`. For 16 of them I also have data starting from different places between 1970 and 1975 to 2017 in `DF2`. What I want to do is to put the 1970-1980 part from `DF2` on top of `DF1`. I guess I would achieve the same result if I managed to merge `DF1` into `DF2` for the cells where they both have values (so `DF1` overrides `DF2`). However, the starting dates are not exactly equal for all currencies, so I can't just hardcode it.

Here is an example to show you what it looks like:
`Date`is the time variable (monthly data). `DF1` would be corresponding to the 1980-2017 data and `DF2` would correspond to the 1970-2017 data. My objective is to override the values from `DF1` into `DF2` based on both column and row ID. `DF3` is the desired output, without the NAs from DF1, just the values from DF2 instead.

```
set.seed(1234)
DF1=data.frame(matrix(data=c(c(4:9),rnorm(30)),6,6))
set.seed(4321)
DF2=data.frame(matrix(data=c(c(1:12),rnorm(36)),12,4))
names(DF1)=c("Date","Currency1","Currency3","Currency6","Currency7","Currency8")
names(DF2)=c("Date","Currency1","Currency2","Currency3")
DF1$Currency3[1:2]=NA
DF1$Currency1[4:5]=NA

> DF1
  Date  Currency1  Currency3   Currency6  Currency7  Currency8
1    4 -1.2070657         NA -0.77625389 -0.8371717 -0.6937202
2    5  0.2774292         NA  0.06445882  2.4158352 -1.4482049
3    6  1.0844412 -0.5644520  0.95949406  0.1340882  0.5747557
4    7         NA -0.8900378 -0.11028549 -0.4906859 -1.0236557
5    8         NA -0.4771927 -0.51100951 -0.4405479 -0.0151383
6    9  0.5060559 -0.9983864 -0.91119542  0.4595894 -0.9359486

> DF2
   Date   Currency1    Currency2   Currency3
1     1 -0.42675738 -1.260985237 -0.09920208
2     2 -0.22361182  1.139464085 -0.23803425
3     3  0.71760679 -1.221781923  0.04778266
4     4  0.84144567  1.573315888  0.29651274
5     5 -0.12835727  0.073477874 -0.83380992
6     6  1.60934721 -1.175115087 -1.37397000
7     7 -0.29716745 -1.588261899  0.14027895
8     8  0.19600465 -0.747380729  0.66212596
9     9  1.24074620  0.483521864  1.13103967
10   10 -0.71869815 -0.003025539 -0.47511202
11   11 -0.06723632 -0.008930402  0.85241411
12   12  0.34436710  0.593357619 -0.75151885
```

I got this answer from a user, but I encountered a new issue, some of the data in `DF1` has `NA`s in it, which this code overrides into `DF2`.

```
library(data.table)
DF3 <- copy(DF2)
nm1 <- names(DF1)[-1]
setDT(DF3)[DF1, (nm1) := mget(paste0("i.", nm1)), on = .(Date)]

    > DF3
    Date  Currency1  Currency2    Currency3   Currency6  Currency7  Currency8
 1:    1  1.1022975 -0.8553646 -0.162309524          NA         NA         NA
 2:    2 -0.4755931 -0.2806230  0.563055819          NA         NA         NA
 3:    3 -0.7094400 -0.9943401  1.647817473          NA         NA         NA
 4:    4 -1.2070657 -0.9685143           NA -0.77625389 -0.8371717 -0.6937202
 5:    5  0.2774292 -1.1073182           NA  0.06445882  2.4158352 -1.4482049
 6:    6  1.0844412 -1.2519859 -0.564451999  0.95949406  0.1340882  0.5747557
 7:    7         NA -0.5238281 -0.890037829 -0.11028549 -0.4906859 -1.0236557
 8:    8         NA -0.4968500 -0.477192700 -0.51100951 -0.4405479 -0.0151383
 9:    9  0.5060559 -1.8060313 -0.998386445 -0.91119542  0.4595894 -0.9359486
10:   10 -0.4658975 -0.5820759 -0.669633580          NA         NA         NA
11:   11  1.4494963 -1.1088896 -0.007604756          NA         NA         NA
12:   12 -1.0686427 -1.0149620  1.777084448          NA         NA         NA
```

Comment: Please, use `set.seed(1234)` to create reproducible data when using random generated values or `sample()`. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, if that helps.

Comment: It is better to use another set.seed() for DF2 so that you will be able to see whether an approach worked or not. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace only the values in `DF3` that have non-missing counterparts in `DF1` you could use `ifelse`.

Using:

```
DF3 <- copy(DF2)
nm1 <- names(DF1)[-1]
nm2 <- names(DF2)
setDT(DF3)[DF1, (nm1) := {n <- seq_along(nm1);
                          lapply(n, function(i) ifelse(is.na(get(paste0("i.", nm1[i]))) & nm1[i] %in% nm2, 
                                                       get(paste0("x.", nm1[i])), 
                                                       get(paste0("i.", nm1[i]))))},
           on = .(Date)]
```

you get:

```
> DF3
    Date   Currency1    Currency2   Currency3   Currency6  Currency7  Currency8
 1:    1 -0.42675738 -1.260985237 -0.09920208          NA         NA         NA
 2:    2 -0.22361182  1.139464085 -0.23803425          NA         NA         NA
 3:    3  0.71760679 -1.221781923  0.04778266          NA         NA         NA
 4:    4 -1.20706575  1.573315888  0.29651274 -0.77625389 -0.8371717 -0.6937202
 5:    5  0.27742924  0.073477874 -0.83380992  0.06445882  2.4158352 -1.4482049
 6:    6  1.08444118 -1.175115087 -0.56445200  0.95949406  0.1340882  0.5747557
 7:    7 -0.29716745 -1.588261899 -0.89003783 -0.11028549 -0.4906859 -1.0236557
 8:    8  0.19600465 -0.747380729 -0.47719270 -0.51100951 -0.4405479 -0.0151383
 9:    9  0.50605589  0.483521864 -0.99838644 -0.91119542         NA -0.9359486
10:   10 -0.71869815 -0.003025539 -0.47511202          NA         NA         NA
11:   11 -0.06723632 -0.008930402  0.85241411          NA         NA         NA
12:   12  0.34436710  0.593357619 -0.75151885          NA         NA         NA
```

---

Used data:

```
set.seed(1234)
DF1=data.frame(matrix(data=c(c(4:9),rnorm(30)),6,6))
set.seed(4321)
DF2=data.frame(matrix(data=c(c(1:12),rnorm(36)),12,4))
names(DF1)=c("Date","Currency1","Currency3","Currency6","Currency7","Currency8")
names(DF2)=c("Date","Currency1","Currency2","Currency3")
DF1$Currency3[1:2]=NA
DF1$Currency1[4:5]=NA
DF1$Currency7[nrow(DF1)]=NA
```

Comment: I'm encountering one issue when trying it on real data. It gives an error saying "`Error in get(paste0("x.", names1[i])) : object 'x.somecurrency' not found`" when running the setDT. I have more currencies in DF1 than DF2 in the real data, could that be the issue?

Comment: @NielsJo It is working on the updated example data as well. Are you using the latest version of *data.table*? Moreover, it is better to use another `set.seed()` for `DF2` so that you will be able to see whether an approach worked or not.

Comment: "[Package data.table version 1.10.4 Index]" is my current version.
I'll try running the code again, maybe I did a trivial mistake somewhere, thanks!

Comment: The example works perfectly, but somehow the real data doesn't. I can run the opposite with DF1 as the copy and getting names from DF2, but when I swap them around it gives the error, which doesn't make sense to me. Almost gone crazy over it, I've tried every iteration possible now.

Comment: @NielsJo Without an example that reproduces the problem, it is a bit hard to say what the exact problem is .....

Comment: Yeah... It sucks. Appreciate the help though, would be nowhere without the gods from stackoverflow.

Comment: I managed to replicate it and track down the error! If you add `NA` to one of the columns in DF1 that are not shared by DF1 and DF2, it will return an error instead of merging it. Try adding `DF1$Currency7[nrow(DF1)]=NA`, you should get the same error.

Comment: @NielsJo thx for updating; I've updated my answer; it does work now

Comment: Take all my upvotes, master thesis will be like a walk in the park now, thank you so much! Happy easter :D

Comment: Even better! :D

Answer (score 1):

**1) sqldf** Perform a left join of `DF1` and `DF2` using `coalesce` to pick out the first non-missing among its arguments:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select Date,
              coalesce(DF1.Currency1, DF2.Currency1) Currency1,
              DF2.Currency2,
              coalesce(DF1.Currency3, DF2.Currency3) Currency3
       from DF2 left join DF1 using (Date)")
```

giving:

```
   Date   Currency1   Currency2  Currency3
1     1  1.12493092 -0.15579551  1.1000254
2     2 -0.04493361 -1.47075238  0.7631757
3     3 -0.01619026 -0.47815006 -0.1645236
4     4 -0.83562860  0.41794156 -0.2533617
5     5  1.59528080  1.35867955  0.6969634
6     6  0.32950780 -0.10278773  1.5117812
7     7 -0.82046840  0.38767161  0.3898432
8     8  0.48742910 -0.05380504 -0.6212406
9     9  0.73832470 -1.37705956 -2.2146999
10   10 -1.98935170 -0.41499456  0.7685329
11   11  0.61982575 -0.39428995 -0.1123462
12   12 -0.05612874 -0.05931340  0.8811077
```

The names could be paramterized like this:

```
Date <- names(DF2)[1]
Currency1 <- names(DF2)[2]
Currency2 <- names(DF2)[3]
Currency3 <- names(DF2)[4]

fn$sqldf("select [$Date],
              coalesce(DF1.[$Currency1], DF2.[$Currency1]) [$Currency1],
              DF2.[$Currency2],
              coalesce(DF1.[$Currency3], DF2.[$Currency3]) [$Currency3]
       from DF2 left join DF1 using ([$Date])")
```

The square brackets are only needed in case the arbitrary names contain special characters.  If that is known not to be the case then the square brackets could be omitted.

Another way to parameterize is to rename the columns of the data frames to standard names, carry out the computation using the standard names and then restore the original names. Here `DF1` and `DF2` have arbitrary column names whereas `DF1x` and `DF2x` have the standard names used above.  This approach could work more generally (e.g. it would also work with the dplyr code shown in (2) ).

```
DF1x <- setNames(DF1, c("Date", "Currency1", "Currency2", "Currency3")
DF2x <- setNames(DF2, c("Date", "Currency1", "Currency3"))

s <- sqldf("select Date,
              coalesce(DF1x.Currency1, DF2x.Currency1) Currency1,
              DF2x.Currency2,
              coalesce(DF1x.Currency3, DF2x.Currency3) Currency3
       from DF2x left join DF1x using (Date)")

names(s) <- names(DF2)
```

**2) dplyr** dplyr can do it in essentially the same manner and even has a `coalesce` function:

```
library(dplyr)
DF2 %>% 
     left_join(DF1, by = "Date") %>%
     transmute(Date,
               Currency1 = coalesce(Currency1.y, Currency1.x),
               Currency2,
               Currency3 = coalesce(Currency3.y, Currency3.x))
```

giving:

```
   Date   Currency1   Currency2  Currency3
1     1  1.12493092 -0.15579551  1.1000254
2     2 -0.04493361 -1.47075238  0.7631757
3     3 -0.01619026 -0.47815006 -0.1645236
4     4 -0.83562860  0.41794156 -0.2533617
5     5  1.59528080  1.35867955  0.6969634
6     6  0.32950780 -0.10278773  1.5117812
7     7 -0.82046840  0.38767161  0.3898432
8     8  0.48742910 -0.05380504 -0.6212406
9     9  0.73832470 -1.37705956 -2.2146999
10   10 -1.98935170 -0.41499456  0.7685329
11   11  0.61982575 -0.39428995 -0.1123462
12   12 -0.05612874 -0.05931340  0.8811077
```

**Note:** The original code defining the inputs in the question did not use `set.seed` making it not reproducible so we used the following which corresponds to the inputs originally shown in the question. (Since then the question has been fixed to add `set.seed`.)

```
DF1 <-
structure(list(Date = 4:9, Currency1 = c(-0.8356286, 1.5952808, 
0.3295078, -0.8204684, 0.4874291, 0.7383247), Currency3 = c(NA, 
NA, 1.5117812, 0.3898432, -0.6212406, -2.2146999)), .Names = c("Date", 
"Currency1", "Currency3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

DF2 <-
structure(list(Date = 1:12, Currency1 = c(1.12493092, -0.04493361, 
-0.01619026, 0.94383621, 0.8212212, 0.59390132, 0.91897737, 0.7821363, 
0.07456498, -1.9893517, 0.61982575, -0.05612874), Currency2 = c(-0.15579551, 
-1.47075238, -0.47815006, 0.41794156, 1.35867955, -0.10278773, 
0.38767161, -0.05380504, -1.37705956, -0.41499456, -0.39428995, 
-0.0593134), Currency3 = c(1.1000254, 0.7631757, -0.1645236, 
-0.2533617, 0.6969634, 0.5566632, -0.6887557, -0.7074952, 0.364582, 
0.7685329, -0.1123462, 0.8811077)), .Names = c("Date", "Currency1", 
"Currency2", "Currency3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"))
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I substitute the manually written column names (currency1-2-3) with an automated script?

Comment: Ill try it out! I updated the original post with a "new issue", mainly because I'm a dumbass.

Comment: For sqldf define variables Date, Currency1, Currency2, Currency having the column names as values and use $Date, etc. in the SQL statement. See addition at the end of point 1.  Alternately just rename the columns to standard names, carry out the computation and restore the names back.  Thie renaming approach would also work with dplyr.  See answer for both approaches.

Comment: Thank you, I'll see if that works. (Did you see the data edit in the main post?)

Comment: I used fixed inputs shown in the Note so the output shown in the answer should correspond to that.  Note that you only need one `set.seed` at the top to make it reproducible.  They other `set.seed` commands do not hurt but are not really needed to make it reproducible.